# Deploy containers from different docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery

Currently I have a **rabbitmq** message broker and multiple **celery workers** that need to be containerized. My problem is, how can I fire up containers using different `docker-compose.yml`? My goal is to start the **rabbitmq** once and for all, and never touch it again.

Currently I have a `docker-compose.yml` for the **rabbitmq**:

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
        ports:
            - "5672:5672"
        expose:
            - "5672"
```

And another `docker-compose.yml` for **celery workers**:

```
version: '2'
services:
    worker:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        environment:
            - CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://admin:mypass@rabbit:5672
        links:
            - rabbit
```

However, when I do `docker-compose up` for **celery workers**, I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to 
amqp://admin:**@rabbit:5672//: failed to resolve broker hostname.
```

Can anyone take a look if there is anything wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have one service per compose file? The point is to define *networks* of containers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the heads up, just to provide more context of my problem: we have a cluster in production, and new versions of code for celery workers are being rolled out once in a while. Therefore, I need to deploy new workers constantly. I am fairly new to docker-compose, and I am not sure how exactly to define networks among containers. Perhaps you would give me more hints? Thanks

Comment: As a follow up to what was said above, you want to have a single `docker-compose` file with multiple services. Doing this will cause docker-compose to handle the network creation for you making your two services (worker and rabbit) available at the hostnames `worker` and `rabbit` respectively.

Comment: You should create an external network and use this pre existing network on each of compose files. See [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). But i would suggest something like docker swarm or kubernetes for this.

Comment: @JackGore Thanks for the reply, I have marked best answer from thomasleveil, it seems like setting up a network will allow containers to access each others host.

Comment: @fxgx that is the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the domain name `rabbit` in your second docker-compose.yml file does not resolve because there is no service with that name in that docker-compose.yml file.

As stated in the comments, one solution is to put both the `rabbit` service and `worker` service in the same docker-compose.yml file. In such a setup, all containers started for those services would join the same docker network and those service names could be resolved to the IP adresses of their containers.

Since having a single docker-compose.yml file is not convenient in your case, you have to find an other way to have the containers originating from different docker-compose.yml files join a same docker network.

To do so, you need to create a dedicated [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) for that purpose:

```
docker network create rabbitNetwork
```

Then, in each docker-compose.yml file, you need to [refer to this network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) in the services definitions:

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
        # ports:
        #    - "5672:5672"  # there is no need to publish ports on the docker host anymore
        expose:
            - "5672"
        networks:
            - rabbitNet

networks:
  rabbitNet:
    external:
      name: rabbitNetwork
```

```
version: '2'
services:
    worker:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        environment:
            - CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://admin:mypass@rabbit:5672
        networks:
            - rabbitNet

networks:
  rabbitNet:
    external:
      name: rabbitNetwork
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, that solves my problem perfectly!

Comment: `Error -2 connecting to redis-credit:6379. Name or service not known`

Answer (score 0):

You can use any file as service definition.
`docker-compose.yml` is default file name but any other name can be passed using `-f` argument.

```sh
docker-compose -f rabbit-compose.yml COMMAND
```